# How do I get the name of a pytest mark for a test function?

Tags: python, pytest

```
import pytest
class TestSomething(object):

    @pytest.mark.somethinga
    def test_something(self):
```

In the function **test_something** I want to check what mark I gave the function, if it's somethinga the function behaves differently than, for instance somethingb.

I think I should use inspect.py (introspection) but I haven't found how to do it. Many thanks guys!

Comment: The decorator should change the function's behaviour, not the other way around (function changes itself based on decorator)...

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to use `inspect` here; the decorator adds an attribute to the function object, it doesn't wrap the object. From the [source code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/715a235b45debf5e71e1409a826d91833014f4b5/_pytest/mark.py#L268-L276):

```
holder = getattr(func, self.name, None)
if holder is None:
    holder = MarkInfo(
        self.name, self.args, self.kwargs
    )
    setattr(func, self.name, holder)
else:
    holder.add(self.args, self.kwargs)
```

you can detect what names were set by iterating over the function attributes:

```
from _pytest.mark import MarkInfo

def function_marks(func):
    return [name for name, ob in vars(func).items() if isinstance(ob, MarkInfo)]
```

or you can just test for the attribute name and assume it is a marker instance:

```
if hasattr(TestSomething.test_something, 'somethinga'):
    # the somethinga mark is set
```

Demo:

```
>>> import pytest
>>> from _pytest.mark import MarkInfo
>>> @pytest.mark.foo
... @pytest.mark.bar
... def demo(): pass
... 
>>> [name for name, ob in vars(demo).items() if isinstance(ob, MarkInfo)]
['foo', 'bar']
>>> demo.foo
<MarkInfo 'foo' args=() kwargs={}>
>>> demo.bar
<MarkInfo 'bar' args=() kwargs={}>
```

Answer (score 3):

I wondered the same thing until I discovered `pytest` has a [request](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#request) fixture which contains its own markers you can iterate over

```py
@pytest.mark.my_custom_mark
def test_my_method(request):
    using_my_custom_mark = False
    for mark in request.node.own_markers:
        if mark.name == 'my_custom_mark':
            using_my_custom_mark = True
            break

    assert using_my_custom_mark is True
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically when you call `pytest.mark.<attribute>` it sets that `<attribute>` as an instance of `_pytest.mark.Markinfo()` on the function you've decorated / marked.

Example:

**Code:**

```
import pytest
from _pytest.mark import MarkInfo


@pytest.mark.foo
def test_foo():
    assert hasattr(test_foo, "foo")
    assert isinstance(test_foo.foo, MarkInfo)


def test_bar():
    assert not hasattr(test_bar, "foo")
```

**Output:**

```
$ py.test -x -s -v test_foo.py 
======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2 -- /home/prologic/bin/python
cachedir: /home/prologic/tmp/.cache
plugins: pylama, cov, cache, pep8, flakes
collected 2 items 

test_foo.py:5: test_foo PASSED
test_foo.py:11: test_bar PASSED

===================================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds =====================================
```

---

The "name" of the "mark" is also stored in `MarkInfo()` as the attribute `name`:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PDB set_trace (IO-capturing turned off) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> /home/prologic/tmp/test_foo.py(8)test_foo()
-> assert hasattr(test_foo, "foo")
(Pdb) dir(test_foo.foo)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__repr__', '_arglist', 'add', 'args', 'kwargs', 'name']
(Pdb) test_foo.foo.name
'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this could help you, but I was having a similar issue when having a function which I had parametrized to run in the same way over different inputs. Some I was expecting to xfail, and for these I wanted to do a particular follow up action. The parameter `zipped_parameters_list` contained all these zipped input parameters together with their specific `pytest.marks` I had created for each of these input sets. These are applied when you use the `pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator. In this case, I could not find the mark specific to that run with that specific set of parameters as indicated in the above answers. Here's how I got it to do what I wanted, which was to see if this particular test_case had been marked with xfail.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("stage_sql_data,stage_mongo_data,test_data",
                         zipped_test_parameters_list,
                         ids=test_ids)
def test_my_test(stage_sql_data, stage_mongo_data, test_data,
                 tmpdir_factory, request):
    # Do my test steps
    # Assertions
    if 'xfail' in [marker.name for marker in request.node.own_markers]:
        do_some_specific_action()
```

Answer (score 0):

Test function marker:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.major_test
def test_foo():
        print("Marker:")
        print(test_foo.pytestmark[0].name)
        assert(True)
```

Pytest input marker:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.major_test
def test_bar():
        print("Marker:")
        print(pytest.config.option.markexpr)
        assert(True)
```